# Apache Spark number by value

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to create a table that has a column with the occurrence number by value.

i.e

```
id    name        date
1     Wendy       2017-01-01
2     Alex        2017-01-01
3     Wendy       2017-01-01
4     Alex        2016-12-31
```

I need to add a column that is the occurrence of a name on a particular date.

```
id    name        date          Event
1     Wendy       2017-01-01    1
2     Alex        2017-01-01    1
3     Wendy       2017-01-01    2
4     Alex        2016-12-31    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectExpr` with `row_number` in sql syntax:

```
df.selectExpr("id", "name", "date", "row_number() over (partition by name, date order by id) as Event").orderBy("id").show()

+---+-----+----------+-----+
| id| name|      date|Event|
+---+-----+----------+-----+
|  1|Wendy|2017-01-01|    1|
|  2| Alex|2017-01-01|    1|
|  3|Wendy|2017-01-01|    2|
|  4| Alex|2016-12-31|    1|
+---+-----+----------+-----+
```